# Purpose of Visit, Visa Denial for Canada...Need Clarification

Tags: canada, visa-refusals, nigerian-citizens, proof-of-ties

Now i have a pressing Question. I might have the intention of re-applying again, but I want to ask a couple of questions as to what might prompt visa refusals. So I am uploading the letter for reviewing.

Presently, I do not have anyone in Canada, Hence i was just thinking starting out with a tourist visa would be key, If i like the place, maybe much later, I could look for maybe Express entry and settle there.... My TRV was refused. And i attached all documents and right now, I cannot say why.

Here is my letter of refusal, since I do not have a family member there I just indicated Tourism on the purpose of visit. I did attach my hotel reservation as well as other documents and affidavits, Please I really do need some form of clarification here, and I did not attach any letter of Explanation as it was deemed optional.

[image: refusal-letter.png]

Comment: To clarify, what was the purpose of your visit? Was it tourism or are you intending to settle in Canada?

Comment: I stated Tourism. like i said , i did not indicate in the Letter of Explanation, I did not even write a letter of Explanation

Comment: Do you have a prior travel history? What ties to your home country do you have? They doubt your intention to leave at the end of your proposed trip, there’s no point reapplying unless you can show a compelling reason such as job, dependent family ties. Unfortunately, as you may be aware, Nigeria is generally deemed a high immigration risk country.